# Golang Regex: FindAllStringSubmatch to []string

Tags: regex, string, go

I download a multiline file from Amazon S3 in format like:

```
ColumnAv1 ColumnBv1 ColumnCv1 ...
ColumnAv2 ColumnBv2 ColumnCv2 ...
```

the file is of type byte. Then I want to parse this with regex:

```
matches := re.FindAllSubmatch(file,-1)
```

then I want to feed result row by row to function which takes `[]string` as input (`string[0]` is `ColumnAv1`, `string[1]` is `ColumnBv2`, ...).

How should I convert result of `[][][]byte` to `[]string` containing first, second, etc row? I suppose I should do it in a loop, but I cannot get this working:

```
for i:=0;i<len(len(matches);i++{
    tmp:=myfunction(???)
}
```

BTW, Why does function `FindAllSubmatch` return `[][][]byte` whereas `FindAllStringSubmatch` return `[][]string`?

(Sorry I don't have right now access to my real example, so the syntax may not be proper)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all explained extensively in the [package's documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/).
Read the parapgraph which explains :

> There are 16 methods of Regexp that match a regular expression and identify the matched text. Their names are matched by this regular expression:
>
> Find(All)?(String)?(Submatch)?(Index)?

In your case, you probably want to use `FindAllStringSubmatch`.

---

In `Go`, a `string` is just a read-only `[]byte`.
You can choose to either keep passing `[]byte` variables around,
or cast the `[]byte` values to `string` :

```
var byteSlice = []byte{'F','o','o'}
var str string

str = string(byteSlice)
```

Comment: I did it, but the reason I use FindAllSubmatch because it takes byte as input. If I download a file the result is bytes, should I convert it at this stage to string?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply iterate through the bytes result as you would do for strings result using two nested loop, and just convert slice of bytes to a string in the second loop:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    f := [][][]byte{{{'a', 'b', 'c'}}}
    for _, line := range f {
        for _, match := range line { // match is a type of []byte
            fmt.Println(string(match))
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/vINSF5yCF_)